# What package to use for database migrations in Go?

Tags: postgresql, go, database-migration

I am fairly new to golang, and trying to identify the best tools for the job. Currently I am evaluating the following packages:

https://github.com/mattes/migrate

https://github.com/DavidHuie/gomigrate

https://bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with these (or other packages) and could provide some comments.

Comment: There's also liquibase. You don't have to use a tool written in your main language.

Comment: FYI, goose is [dead](https://bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/issues/58/is-this-project-dead).

Comment: @ferhatelmas https://github.com/pressly/goose a maintained fork

Comment: https://github.com/lopezator/migrator might be another option.

Answer (score 2):

We use `mattes/migrate` at work and are very happy with it. It works with plain SQL files, handles file naming by itself and can easily be [automated via CLI](https://github.com/mattes/migrate#usage-from-terminal). It doesn't do anything Go specific.

With `gomigrate` you need to create the files [yourself](https://github.com/DavidHuie/gomigrate#migration-files) and [write code](https://github.com/DavidHuie/gomigrate#usage) for executing the migrations.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/pressly/goose, a maintained fork of https://bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/.